# Story identification - starships powered by captured gods?

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a short story many, many years ago. One of the major plot elements was that there was a ship powered by some sort of captured god or deity, but I can't recall much more than that? Perhaps something like that they were travelling around the galaxy capturing gods to feed to their own, or something? It's such an obscure idea that I hope that this detail alone might be enough that someone else might be able to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 10):

Sounds very much like [The God Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_God_Engines) by John Scalzi.

From Wikipedia entry:

> The story takes place in a universe where space travel is accomplished
>   by chaining intelligent, human-like creatures called gods to a
>   spacecraft and torturing them to drive the ship. The people are ruled
>   by an organization called the Bishopry Militant, who worship a
>   powerful being. Captain Ean Tephe is completely faithful to the
>   Bishopry, but his faith comes under test when he is assigned a secret
>   mission which his ship's god seems to have a keen interest in

.